# How does exchange rate affect the degree of local firms competitiveness?

Tags: inflation, currency-exchange

It's written in my textbook that:

> Inflation causes exports to become less internationally competitive as their prices increase. So, demand for exports decreases.

It's written in another lesson in my textbook that:

> Depreciation of a currency can be caused by low demand on exports.

So, I concluded that if inflation occur, prices of exports go up and demand on them decrease, in addition, this drop in demand will also depreciate the country's currency.

My question is will this depreciation of currency causes demand on exports to rise again? Also, if a company exports products and it uses imports in the production, will it lose or gain from this depreciation? I tried to calculate the answer of my last question myself but I got different calculations each time. It's like it will gain at some prices and lose if it exceeds them.